# How does Windows Explorer extract EXE file's icon

Tags: windows, winapi, dll, windows-explorer

It's my guess.

We list a files and directory by Windows Explorer.
If Windows Explorer meets a exe file, it does,

> LoadLibraryEx(ExefileName, LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE)
>   Then extracts the icon, and represents it.

But I'm not sure.
Is there anyone who knows well about this?

I'm finding a nice case with LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE
Is there anything else you know?

Comment: Take a look at the source code for IconLib (C#), it can read icon files from .exes so that might help you: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/IconLib.aspx

Answer (score 2):

there is a win32api called ExtractIconEx.

this is exactly what you are looking for.. :)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648069%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: ExtractionIconEx doesn't call LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE.
It just parses PE image by itself.

Comment: @Benjamin: And what are you actually trying to do? The answer is pretty much correct, this is basically what Explorer does.

Comment: I was under the assumption that explorer also used standard win32 apis.. I could be wrong of course :)

Comment: @0xA3 Yes it is. My question was stupid. What I wanted is a nice example using LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE.

Comment: @Benjamin: if you want to use LoadLibrary, then you'd need to use LoadResource(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648046(VS.85).aspx) & FindResource(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648042(v=VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Some more detailed info by Raymond Chen:

> **[How the shell converts an icon location into an icon](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100505-00/?p=14153)**